# connecting to AWS server where docker is deployed through template

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-aws

I am following the article that I found here...

https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/install/aws/

I am able to deploy the template, but I do not see the UCP and DTR URLs in the output tab.

Actually there are only 2 parameters in the output tab. DefaultDNSTarget and Managers. How do I connect to docker swarm?

Answer (score 0):

I need to connect to Public IP of Docker Manager instance. For e.g. if the IP is 52.90.20.41 then the ssh command will look something like this...

```
ssh -i yourkey.pem docker@52.90.20.41
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "Managers" Parameter of the output tab the value should be a URL that will redirect you to a filtered view of the EC2 Instances that are the managers. There you will see the PublicIpAddresses of the managers.